# How to decode strings saved in utf-8 format

Tags: python, string, utf-8

I'm trying to decode the strings in the list below. They were all encoded in utf-8 format.

```
_strs=['."\n\nThe vicar\'',':--\n\nIn the', 'cathedral']
```

Expected output:

```
['.The vicar', ':--In the', 'cathedral']
```

My attempts

```
>>> for x in _str:
    x.decode('string_escape')
    print x


'."\n\nThe vicar\''
."

The vicar'
':--\n\nIn the'
:--

In the
'cathedral'
cathedral
>>> print [x.decode('string_escape') for x in _str]
['."\n\nThe vicar\'', ':--\n\nIn the', 'cathedral']
```

Both attempts failed. 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

So you want to remove some characters from your list, it can be done using a simple `regex` like in the following:

```
import re
print [re.sub(r'[."\'\n]','',x) for x in _str]
```

this `regex` removes all the (`.`, `"`, `'`, `\n`) and the result will be:

```
['The vicar', ':--In the', 'cathedral']
```

hope this helps.

Comment: I want to retain all the punctuation marks. Sorry I did not state that in my question or expected output. The punctuation marks are too many, I don't know of any method that decodes automatically other than selective removal of unwanted character using a reg-ex.

Comment: any characters you want to keep, don't put in the regex. so if you want the `.` to be in the output like your last edit, then make the regex = `["\'\n]`

Comment: you are right about that, but my dataset is too large, and the characters are numerous. If there's no standard method for decoding, then I'll have to build a punctuation list and adopt your solution. Thanks a lot bro.